# Can the value _edata be inferred by info in the ELF Header or Program Header?

Tags: c, operating-system, embedded, elf, bsp

Is there any information in the [elf headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) that show where [_edata](http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF) is located?

Am aware I can search the whole image for the symbol but would like to know where it is from information in the headers...

Comment: @ooga: it is a symbol in the image that marks the end of data.

Comment: But it doesn't appear anywhere on the page that you've linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual address (`p_vaddr`) of the data segment (the `PT_LOAD` segment that's writable) plus its size on disk (`p_filesz`) gives you the equivalent of `_edata` if you mean for it to be just past the end of initialized data and before bss. If you also want to count bss, use the full size in memory (`p_memsz`) instead of the size on disk.